# How to elegant the first time show popup with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to show user a popup for the first time they come to my site.

I did it that way,

When the user comes in the first time, the cookies has nothing,

so I will show popup, and save a flag to cookie.

The next time user comes, the popup won't show.

However, I think my implementation smells bad, seems not in a Rails way.

How can I improve it ?

## View

```
- unless @has_shown_price_hint
  :javascript
    $("#hint_for_price").fadeToggle(2000);
    document.cookie="has_shown_hint_for_price=true";
```

## Controller

```
  def index
    @has_shown_price_hint = (cookies['has_shown_hint_for_price'].nil?)? false : true
  end
```

Comment: You could at least shorten the method and make it a bit more readable like this: `@has_shown_price_hint = cookies['has_shown_hint_for_price'].present?`

Comment: This may be a better fit for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can add login counter to user. It's a great idea by itself to know how loyal your users are.

Then checking if the user is the first-time visitor is just checking condition:

```
def first_time_visitor?
  login_count == 0
end
```